# how to fix "Exception has occurred: SSLError HTTPSConnectionPool" in VS Code environment

Tags: python, windows, ssl, error-handling

i try to use python requests library but i got this error
i use psiphon VPN most of time in Windows 10
and got this below error after calling `requests.get('[API URL]')`

```
Exception has occurred: SSLError
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /user (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\Hessam\Desktop\QWE.py", line 3, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try to add `verify=False` to your request:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', verify=False)
```

`requests` verifies SSL certificates for HTTPS requests, just like a web browser. By default, SSL verification is enabled, and `requests` will throw an SSLError if it’s unable to verify the certificate.

In your specific case, you most likely have a problem with the SSL certificate on your VPN.

Note that when `verify` is set to `False`, `requests` will accept any TLS certificate presented by the server, and will ignore hostname mismatches and/or expired certificates, which will make your application vulnerable to man-in-the-middle (MitM) attacks. Setting `verify` to `False` may be useful during local development or testing.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.