# SSLError: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443)

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, sentence-transformers

I would like to use the `SentenceTransformers` like from this [page](https://www.sbert.net/). When running the following code I get an error which I'm not able to solve:

```
import torch
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

sentences = ['This framework generates embeddings for each input sentence',
    'Sentences are passed as a list of string.',
    'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.']

model = SentenceTransformer("paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2")
embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
```

This returns the following error:

```
SSLError: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/models/sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2 (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)')))"), '(Request ID: b875fc51-82ec-4309-94ab-0d08f9ab067d)')
```

I'm using `Python 3.10.12` with the following packages version:

```
torch                    2.0.1
sentence-transformers    2.2.2
requests                 2.31.0
```

I tried to add the following code like from this question ([how to fix "Exception has occurred: SSLError HTTPSConnectionPool" in VS Code environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70481851/how-to-fix-exception-has-occurred-sslerror-httpsconnectionpool-in-vs-code-env)):

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://huggingface.com', verify=False)
```

Unfortunately, this also returns an error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)')))
```

I also tried to use `verify=ssl.CERT_NONE` instead of `verify=False` like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55680224/how-to-fix-requests-exceptions-sslerror), but this also doesn't work.

Finally, I added this code and downgraded `requests` to `2.27.1` like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75110981/sslerror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-huggingface-co-port-443-max-retries-exce):

```
import os

os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = ''
```

Also this doesn't work. So I was wondering if anyone knows why this error happens and how to fix this?

Comment: Did you chase this one down?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410577/python-requests-exceptions-sslerror-eof-occurred-in-violation-of-protocol

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the OpenSSL 3. I believe you are using a Linux OS which come with openssl 3.

This solution will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77177494/2018712